# How can i convert Android Path Object To SVG Path Tag?

Tags: android, graphics, svg, tags, drawing

How can i convert the following Android Path representation to SVG Path representation?
This points are used by the Android Path class to draw free form entries, how can i convert them to SVG Path tag?

```
"pointList": 
[  
    {
      "x": 822.94635,
      "y": 266.12482
    },
    {
        "x": 824.1951,
        "y": 266.12482
    },

   ...

    {
        "x": 979.0439,
        "y": 186.02078
    },
    {
        "x": 979.0439,
        "y": 186.02078
    }
]
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the points? Connect them with straight lines? Curves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the points are to be drawn in a sequence with straight lines. In this case, you have to generate one move-to (`M`) command, followed by several line-to (`L`) commands and separate them with spaces to generate the SVG path `d` attribute.

You start with *move-to* generating

```
var d = "M" + pointList[0].x + "," + pointList[0].y;
```

Then the others in a `pointList.length - 1` loop with *line-to*, adding spaces between the commands:

```
d += " " + "L" + pointList[i].x + "," + pointList[i].y;
```

And you'll have a the data for the SVG path.

You should be aware that the positions are relative to the view port definitions.

Comment: Well i checked the implementation they were using the first element as M move to and at the other points they used quadratic bezier

Comment: In that case you will use `M`, `Q` and probably `T` (tangential). `Q` is quadratic bezier which takes two pairs of x,y (control-point and end-point). You will have to discover which ones correspond to them in your data. `T` continues a previous curve through a tangent, so it only uses one pair. You can read more about that here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html The examples are very detailed and clear.

Comment: Anyone knows of any open source parser that does the opposite? Svg paths to Android Paths.